# PRIMARY KEY VIOLATION error in Windows Forms?

Tags: c#, .net, winforms

I want to add a New Database Entry but it is giving PRIMARY KEY VIOLATION.
Any Solution?
I am getting this error in the windows forms app.
Using ADO.NET SQL database.
the primary key is the (id) which is int.
I am getting errors in register users.
Field are name, password, address, cell_no, email.
these fields are String (max length: 50)

[image]

My Code:

```
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.ComponentModel;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.Entity.Validation;
using System.Drawing;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace WindowsFormsApp2
{
    public partial class registeruser : Form
    {
        demoEntities db = new demoEntities();
        String Id;
        public registeruser()
        {
            Id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void registeruser_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {

        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            
            user_details usd = new user_details();
            usd.name = textBox1.Text;
            usd.password = textBox2.Text;
            usd.address = textBox3.Text;
            usd.cell_no = textBox4.Text;
            usd.email = textBox5.Text;
            
            
            try
            {
                db.user_details.Add(usd);
                if (db.SaveChanges() > 0)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Data Saved Successfully");
                }
                else
                {
                    MessageBox.Show("Error while Saving Data");
                }
            }
            catch(DbEntityValidationException dbEx)
            {
                foreach (var validationErrors in dbEx.EntityValidationErrors)
                {
                    foreach (var validationError in validationErrors.ValidationErrors)
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine("Property: {0} Error: {1}", validationError.PropertyName, validationError.ErrorMessage);
                    }
                }



            }
        }
    }
}
```

[[1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mhF6s.jpg](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gXWsQ.jpg)

Comment: It may be that you didn't set the column to be `IDENTITY` when creating the table, or that you're just not populating the id from your code.

Comment: How did you manage to misspell PRIMART KEY VOILATION *twice* in the same way in the same post?

Comment: If you're using SQL you should let the database assign primary keys, not try to assign them from the application.

Answer (score 3):

I'm assuming you are using SQL Server. The problem is, you have already a user with id == 0 and the app is trying to add another. At this point you have 2 options so far as I know..

1. In SQL Server Management Studio -> find your table -> design and click on the id column. In the bottom (Column Properties) set it to this: [Column Properties id](https://i.stack.imgur.com/gczNS.png)

2. You increase the id in the code.. I don't usually because it can cause other issues.

Comment: Assuming it is SQL Being used, I vote this answer as correc